# Receive Location polling data after service window stop time

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We have a BizTalk 2013 R2 server where a receive location is configured to polling some data from a database every 10 min within a specified service window (9 am to 9 pm).

For some reason it started to polling data from the database after the specified service window time.

Has anyone experienced this or know why this happens in BizTalk 2013 R2.

Comment: And the "Enable service window" check box is checked?  Can you add a screenshot of the configuration?

Comment: Are you using wcf sql adapter polling sql server data? And how do you know it start polling data after the service window?

Comment: Hi Yes, the "Enable service window" is checked. The stop time is set to 9 pm. 
We have a monitoring system , where we keep track on all data polling from the database using the mentioned receive location configuration, and here we can see that data is sent after 9 pm.

Comment: Yes we are using wcf sql adapter polling. The SQL polling is set to every 10 min within the service window.

Comment: I can now confirm that yes, we had one poll occur at a clients just outside of the service window in BizTalk 2013 R2 CU1. We are going to get the client to update to CU4 although we cannot see any fixes related to this issue in the CUs, but you need to be on the latest CU to be able to raise an issue with Microsoft.    Which CU does the server that is experiencing the issue have?

Answer (score 1):

Problems in BizTalk 2020.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5003153-fix-scheduled-receive-location-polling-outside-service-window-ae003f50-1aa3-44da-bd7f-9770daf7fe1b

You need to install CU2 to have this fixed.

Comment: Not yet confirmed by me...

Comment: Setting the same time zone on ALL receive locations, including the one that does not use scheduling, resolved my problem while waiting for the CU2 to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have had this happen once at a clients site with BizTalk 2013 R2 CU1.

No, we have not got a root cause for the issue yet, it has only happened once.

Now I'm going to answer you unasked question, "What to do about it?".

One of the first steps to do would be to ensure that your BizTalk server is updated to the latest Cumulative Update, currently CU4 (see [kb 3167705](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3167705)) but you should always check what the latest CU is here,  [kb 2555986 Service Pack and cumulative update list for BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2555976).  This is what we are going to recommend to our client even though we could not see a particular fix in the updates that mentions this particular issue.  This will then allow you to raise the issue with Microsoft if the issue persists.  If you didn't do the CU first, one of the first questions Microsoft asks is "What CU are you on?" and if it is not the latest one that would be the first thing they ask you to do.

Meanwhile to address the problem you may want to change the polling statement in the Receive Location to call a stored procedure in the database that contains the logic to say if it should fetch any data or not, in your case only between 9 am and 9 pm.  I know it goes a bit against the grain to take that configuration out of BizTalk and into the database or to duplicate the logic database, but it would ensure that the rule is enforced.

In our clients case we only want to allow it to get data once a day around a certain time, so we will probably* have it store the last date data was fetched, if that date is set to the current date the polling stored procedure should return zero rows.

- I'm not the tech-lead/developer for that particular client, so this is just my opinion.